# Setting checkbox input when specific value equals variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use JQuery to set a checkbox to checked if the input value of the checkbox is equal to some other variable that I have. This is what my code looks like:

```
var test_val = "test";
$('#checkbox[value='+test_val+']').attr('checked', true);
```

This does not seem to be working, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#checkbox[value="'+test_val+'"]').attr('checked', true);
```

you were missing the quotes around the value.

Comment: the quotes shouldn't be needed. i'm guessing something else is wrong here.